# Conditions for a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

If 4 points taken in clockwise order A(1,-1);B(-2,0);C(1,2); and D(x,y) Form the vertices of a parallelogram, then what is the coordinate of D?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn a figure?  Show it!  The answer will be obvious.

Comment: As ABCD is a parallelogram, the diagonals must bisect each other so, midpoint of AC is (1,0.5) which should be the midpoint of BD ((x-2)/2,y/2) hence x=4,y=1 so I am getting the coordinates of D as (4,1). Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. The diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.
2. The mid point of the line segment joining $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$.

I am sure you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(1,-1), B(-2,0), C(1,2), D(h,k)$, $m_{AB}=m_{CD} \implies \frac{-1}{3}=\frac{2-k}{1-h} \implies 6-3k=h-1~~~(1)$. Similarly, $m_{BC}=m_{AD} \implies \frac{2}{3}=\frac{k+1}{h-1} \implies 2(h-1)=3(k+1)~~~(2)$
Solving (1) and (2), we get $D(4,1)$.

Comment: I think you have flipped the coordinates of A and B A is (1,-1);B is(-2,0), Also ABCD taken in clockwise order should form a parallelogram. The point D should lie on a parallel line to AB, so both points to right or left of C is possible but only four point to the right of C, i.e., D=(4,1) would ABCD form a parallelogram with vertices written in clockwise order.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have corrected my anser now. Thanks.